# Replace following n elements based on a conditional statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to replace elements based on a conditional statement. For example

```
df=c(1,2,"b","b",1,2,2,"b",2,1,2,2,"b",1,1,2)
for(i in 1:length(df)){
 if (df[i]=="b"){
  df[i+1]="N"
  df[i+2]="N"
  df[i+3]="N"
 }
}
df
[1] "1" "2" "b" "N" "N" "N" "2" "b" "N" "N" "N" "2" "b" "N" "N" "N"
```

I want to find a simple way to do it becasue I need replace following 90 elements in my dataframe. So I've tried the below which doesn't give the desired output.

```
n=3
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  if (df[i]=="b"){df[i+1:i+n]="N"}
}
df
[1] "1" "2" "b" "b" "1" "2" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "2" "b" "1" "1" "2" "N"  "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N"
```

Thank you very much for any help or suggestion.

Comment: This? `ifelse(df == "b", c("b", rep("N",3)), df)`

Comment: Sorry, I delete the comment by mistake.

Comment: @Jimbou, then the output is   "1" "2" "N" "N" "1" "2" "2" "N" "2" "1" "2" "2" "b" "1" "1" "2.

Comment: `replace(df, c(sapply(which(df == "b"), function(i) i + 1:3)), "N")` also doesn't give the desired output. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JaneZ, your code has a mistake, it should be `(i+1):(i+n)` instead of `i+1:i+n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code in the following way:

```
for(i in 1:length(df)){
        if (df[i]=="b"){
                df[i+1:3]<-"N"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use in this way:

```
df=c(1,2,"b","b",1,2,2,"b",2,1,2,2,"b",1,1,2)
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  if (df[i]=="b"){
    df[(i+1):(i+3)] <- "N"
  }
}
```